# How to filter TreeViewAdv with RecordFilters

Tags: c#, .net, syncfusion

I am new to C# and SyncFusion and would really appreciate your help.

I need to have the correct records shown in `TreeViewPresenter(TreeViewAdv)` after filtering `gridGroupingControl`.

First I thought about to get the filters with:

```
detailGroupingControl.TableDescriptor.RecordFilters
```

and to set these filters in the `TreeViewPresenter` but it seems that it doesn't work like that. Are there any easy methods to filter the tree with the same filtering criterias as `gridGroupingControl`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add the RecordFilters from one TreeView node to another TreeView node, you have to add the objects of the grid in a  list. Using this list, the filtering can be reflected to all the TreeView nodes. Please refer the below code and sample for reference,

```
//Used to save the objects of all grids
List<GridGroupingControl> grids = new List<GridGroupingControl>();

//add the grid to the list
grids.Add(GridGroupingControl);

void RecordFilters_Changed(object sender, Syncfusion.Collections.ListPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Syncfusion.Grouping.RecordFilterDescriptorCollection filters = sender as RecordFilterDescriptorCollection;
    foreach (GridGroupingControl grid in grids)
    {
        foreach(RecordFilterDescriptor filter in filters)
        {
            //To avoid the repeated objects from the list
            if (grid.TableDescriptor.RecordFilters.Contains(filter))
                continue;
            grid.TableDescriptor.RecordFilters.Add(filter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're Setting the filters to the grid but I wanted them to filter my Tree nodes. The Tree doesn't own methods like  .TableDescriptor.RecordFilters.Add(filter); At the Moment I'm just putting each row from grid into my tree in a loop